# how to update a php global variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to update the PHP global counter on click of a button in Javascript. The reason I'm using PHP global variable instead of JavaScript global variable is that initially the records come from database which can be done using of course only PHP. Below is the code for that

```
       $('#AddOpponent').click(function(){
              <?php  $GLOBALS['counter']=$GLOBALS['counter']+1; ?>
              var c=<?php echo $GLOBALS['counter'];?>
               //c=c+1;
              var str="<br> <br> <p>Opponent No " + c +"</p> <select id=\"opponent_id" + c +"\"          name=\"opponent_id" + c +"\" class=\"form-control input sm select2\">" + options +"</select>";
             $( "#AppendForm" ).append(str);
             $("#Oppcounter").val(c);
             //alert(str);
    
    
        });
```

**EDIT:** Instead of incrementing the PHP global variable, copying it's value to a js variable and then incrementing on button click. Apparently showing the same result as '3' on every button click

```
        $('#AddOpponent').click(function(){
           c=<?php echo $GLOBALS['counter'];?>
           c=c+1;
          var str="<br> <br> <p>Opponent No " + c +"</p> <select id=\"opponent_id" + c +"\"  name=\"opponent_id" + c +"\" class=\"form-control     input sm select2\">" + options +"</select>";
         $( "#AppendForm" ).append(str);
         $("#Oppcounter").val(c);
         //alert(str);
    });
```

but it updates just once . For example if the current counter is 2, on every click of the button the counter shows as just 3 always
PS: There are no errors in the console

Thanks

Comment: `how to update a php global variable in javascript?` .... well why would a php var be global in javascript? Two different run-times

Comment: Ok I see. Yeah your `echo` on php side just renders *once*, when the page is loaded. Look into ajax. .... You cant mix php on front-side to "re-render". It only does its work once.

Comment: You could use ajax to update the value in php. Also don't use a global but use a value in the database instead.

Comment: Because I want to continue from the counter where the record from db ended. For example a particular case has two opponents so the records should appear with the label of counter as opponent 1, opponent 2 so when the user clicks add opponent button, the next drop down's label should start from 3.

Comment: I meant it shouldn't have two counters for the same thing and it has to be starting from the same counter. it was an answer to your first comment since I hadn't received your 2nd comment at that time

Comment: You need to set the JS copy of the counter once in JS copying it from the PHP value) when the page loads, and then use JavaScript to increase it every time the button is clicked. The way you've got it now, the value resets every time the button is clicked. I don't think you actually need to send the value back to PHP here, as far as I can tell (and contrary to what GetSet is saying)

Comment: And  ' I want to continue` was said in context of the counter since obviously I wouldn't want to discontinue that counter and start another

Comment: ADyson. Followed your suggestion of copying PHP global variable value to a  js variable and then incrementing on button-click but still the counter shows 3 on every click. You can check the edited question to check the edited code if I didn't understand your point

Comment: You're still resetting it every time the button is clicked. The line `c=<?php echo $GLOBALS['counter'];?>` needs to be _outside_ the click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem is that `c` is reset every time your button is clicked.

Consider this code:

```
$('#AddOpponent').click(function(){
    c=<?php echo $GLOBALS['counter'];?>
    c=c+1;
```

If, for example, `$GLOBALS['counter'];` is 3 when PHP executes this, then the final version of the Javascript which is sent to your browser will be

```
$('#AddOpponent').click(function(){
    c=3
    c=c+1;
```

Therefore, `c` will reset to `3` every time you click the button.

You just need to move that line outside the click event handler, so that it runs only once, when the page and Javascript are first loaded into the browser.

e.g.

```
var c=<?php echo $GLOBALS['counter'];?>;

$('#AddOpponent').click(function(){
    c=c+1;
```

Comment: Did that. Now nothing is happening on button click

Comment: I assume you kept the rest of the code? This is just a snippet. Are there any errors in the Console? Did you attempt any other debugging? "nothing is happening" isn't a useful description of the problem. Please try to do some basic debugging.

Comment: There needs to be added a semicolon at the end of `c=<?php echo $GLOBALS['counter'];?>` as `c=<?php echo $GLOBALS['counter'];?>
;` . It works perfectly fine after that

Comment: Ah ok. I just took exactly from your version. JS doesn't always need semicolons at line ends. Anyway glad that's all it was. I'll update the answer.